# Book where a human is purified by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been looking for a book for years, but have very little detail about it (if it's even right). I don't know title or author. I do remember that I enjoyed it immensely!

What I can remember is (I think), there was a farmer (boy/man) who looked after sheep or cattle and aliens (I think they were cat like/feline) who removed all the toxins and impurities (caused by earths environment) from the boy. The boy became really strong and fast as all of a sudden he was picking up sheep? etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please check out the [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if there are any other details you can add, like when you read the story, or how old the book was.

Comment: There's a bunch of [questions about feline aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+feline+aliens+is%3Aq) and [ones with cat-like aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+cat+like+aliens+is%3Aq). You might want to take a look - even if some of them aren't answered, maybe you're looking for one of these and it might remind you of other details :)